# extracting alphanumeric values following some given text in a sentence

Tags: regex, stanford-nlp

I want to extract some alphanumeric values in a sentence.The values will be after or before some given text pattern. I have already tries regexner tool of stanford nlp.But i want to do it using some other tool like tokenregex of parse.
situation.To enter the building code is 123A.The access code is 456.There are many sentences like these two .I want to extract the code values from sentences like this.

Comment: SO frowns upon questions that ask for plug-ins, libraries or tools to do something. SO is geared towards assisting you debugging programming code that you have written.

Comment: Do you have any code to show what you have done/tried? Do you have a sample input/output?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer to this is "look for any number of letters, then look for at least one (can be more) digit, followed by any number of letters."

So you end up with something like [/\w*\d+\w*/](https://regex101.com/r/iJ1vI4/1). If the regex engine you use doesn't understand `\w` or `\d`, you can also try `/[a-z]*[0-9]+[a-z]*/` instead.